# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Проблема возникает на 2 ПК, на одном windows 8, на другом windows 10

На пк с Windows 10 AVX нет. На пк с Windows 8 AVX есть. Пробовал и GPU и CPU версии tensorflow, не помогает.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Documents\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import predictor
    File "C:\Users\User\Documents\predictor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

    for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
    above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Удалось победить или нет? Я сейчас на ноуте с Win 10 с такой же проблемой бьюсь (

Comment: Где-то в итоге нашел скомпилированный под sse 2.0 tensorflow, и поставил его